# weird MVC2 Cookies problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, cookies, localhost

I am having a cookie problem in the below example. the cookie does get created and when i put a debug point after its creation i can check whats in the cookie with a watch. however, when i restart the website, the cookie is still there, but has become empty and will not create the model (all fields empty are null.)

I looked around and found bugs relating to using response.Cookie and having no expiry date, but i changed things around and it stays empty.  Am i doing something wrong or is this because im using localhost?

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Autorize]
    public ActionResult ManagePaymentRun()
    {
            ViewData["currentAction"] = "Index";
            payments.AccountNo = Request.Cookies["FSCSPayments"]["AccountNo"];
            payments.SortCode = Request.Cookies["FSCSPayments"]["SortCode"];
            payments.FirstChequeNo = "2";// Request.Cookies["FSCSPayments"]["FirstChequeNo"]; 
            payments.FileName = Request.Cookies["FSCSPayments"]["FileName"];
            payments.FRN = Request.Cookies["FSCSPayments"]["FRN"];
            payments.JobNumber = Request.Cookies["FSCSPayments"]["JobNumber"];
            payments.StartRecNo = Request.Cookies["FSCSPayments"]["StartRecNo"]; 
            return View(payments);
    }

    internal void CreateCookie()
    {

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("FSCSPayments");
        cookie.Values.Add("AccountNo", payments.AccountNo);
        cookie.Values.Add("SortCode", payments.SortCode);
        cookie.Values.Add("FirstChequeNo", payments.FirstChequeNo);
        cookie.Values.Add("FileName", payments.FileName);
        cookie.Values.Add("FRN", payments.FRN);
        cookie.Values.Add("JobNumber", payments.JobNumber);
        cookie.Values.Add("StartRecNo", payments.StartRecNo);
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14);
        cookie.Path = "/";
        Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```

Comment: If a future expiration date isnt set for the cookie, then its a session level cookie and will generally be destroyed when the browser closes or the session times out (depending upon the particular browser).
Where in your code are you calling `CreateCookie()`? When you say you restart the website and the cookie is there, what do you mean? You find it in the browser's cookie cache? If the cookie is being persisted, then it is independent of the server's stops and starts.

Comment: If i search the cookie cache, it is there. I have added  an add days to my cookie, so it shouldn't be session cookie right? and the createcookie is called in the ManagePaymentRun HttpPost action, and i have set a debug point in create cookie and it does pass there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved and was due to the fact that i used IIS 5 and MVC. we copied this project over to a IIS7 pc now and we got the cookies working.

Answer (score 1):

```
cookie.Path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Andy\\Cookies";
```

This is not intended to do what you think it does. You cannot specify where the cookie will be stored on the client computer. That's absolutely browser dependent and you have no control over it. It is to restrict the access of this cookie to certain parts of your site. So if you don't want restriction simply set it to `cookie.Path = "/"`.

Also your `ManagePaymentRun` action method looks strange. Why testing whether the user is authenticated when there's the `[Autorize]` attribute:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult ManagePaymentRun()
{
    ViewData["currentAction"] = "Index";
    var payments = new Payments();
    payments.AccountNo = Request.Cookies["FSCSPayments"]["AccountNo"];
    payments.SortCode = Request.Cookies["FSCSPayments"]["SortCode"];
    payments.FirstChequeNo = "2";// Request.Cookies["FSCSPayments"]["FirstChequeNo"]; 
    payments.FileName = Request.Cookies["FSCSPayments"]["FileName"];
    payments.FRN = Request.Cookies["FSCSPayments"]["FRN"];
    payments.JobNumber = Request.Cookies["FSCSPayments"]["JobNumber"];
    payments.StartRecNo = Request.Cookies["FSCSPayments"]["StartRecNo"]; 
    return View(payments);
}
```

Comment: I never heard of the Authorize attribute before but iv'e added it now. it's great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should trobleshoot the problem, I have 3 suggestions:

1) cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays (14);

2) be careful with the .Add(Key, Value), Values should be safe not contain some symbols, althoug i think an exception is raised

3) specify the cookie.path

but my bet is the first one.

Comment: Yes, I'd agree with your first point. OP calls cookie.Expires.AddDays(14); but does not assign this value back to cookie.Expires. I'm guessing that cookie.Expires might even initialise to DateTime.MinValue too.

Comment: i've tried 1 and 3. in my test case, i add 16 to all fields, so there wont be any strange elements there. however, when adding the path, i do not find the cookie at that path.